# AJAX enters data twice in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function where a user can a report a post, the user clicks the report button, and then promptly enters the information for the report. This works, the problem is if the page hasn't reloaded and the user decided to report a second post the data for that report enters the database twice. Why is this?

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".report_post").click(function(e) {
    var nid = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#report_reason").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
    });

    $('.submit_report_post').click(function() {
      var content = $("#report_content").val();
      var type = "Post";
      if ($('input[name="report"]:checked').length > 0 && (content != null &&
        content != "")) {
        var complaint = document.querySelector('input[name="report"]:checked').value;
        alert('Reported!');
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'php/report_post.php',
          data: {
            type: type,
            nid: nid,
            reason: complaint,
            content: content,
          },
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            $("#report_content").val("");
            $("input[name='report']").prop('checked', false);
            //$("#report_reason").dialog('close');
          }
        });
      } else {
        alert('Fill all of the information!');
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Multiple things you can do. Create an array with id of button. When the button is clicked, insert the id in array. And before sending ajax request, check if value is already inside array. Hope it's clear enougth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding `click` on `$('.submit_report_post')` every time you click on `$(".report_post")`, you need to do it outside of first bind

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".report_post").click(function(e) {
    var nid = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#report_reason").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.submit_report_post').click(function() {
    var content = $("#report_content").val();
    var type = "Post";
    if ($('input[name="report"]:checked').length > 0 && (content != null &&
      content != "")) {
      var complaint = document.querySelector('input[name="report"]:checked').value;
      alert('Reported!');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/report_post.php',
        data: {
          type: type,
          nid: nid,
          reason: complaint,
          content: content,
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          $("#report_content").val("");
          $("input[name='report']").prop('checked', false);
          //$("#report_reason").dialog('close');
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert('Fill all of the information!');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution, I'm just wondering on how to pass the           `var nid = $(this).attr("id"); `to the ajax script? I've tried creating a separate `var nid `inside the `submit_report_post` and it worked.

Comment: Nevermind, figured how to pass the `var nid`. Thanks for this solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You're submitting your form twice, once the normal way and once via AJAX. You have `e.preventDefault();` in your code which would normally stop the typical non-AJAX submission, however you never created the `e` argument.

Change:

```
$('.submit_report_post').click(function() {
```

to

```
$('.submit_report_post').click(function(e) {
```

and this will make the form only submit through the AJAX code.